# python scipy.ndimage.zoom to resize 3D mask

Tags: python, scipy

I use scipy.ndimage.zoom() to resize 3D ndarray which represent mask.

```
resize_img = itpl.zoom(img, (resize[0] / img.shape[0], resize[1] / img.shape[1], resize[2] / img.shape[2]), mode='nearest')
```

But the result is not just 1 and 0.

[image]

I don't know why.

Comment: If anyone know the math behind 3D array mask resize interpolation will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the nearest is still doing a 3 order interpolation. Add argument order=0 with mode='nearest' and I think your problem is fixed :)